# VIM tab oddities, have to retab every save?

Tags: vim

Ok, this is really weird.  I have used VIM forever, literally twenty years.  And now I have a very weird behavior. This just started this week.

My whitespace is getting screwed up with almost every edit.

I have long working code.  I open it up, use "o" to add a line, even just a print statement, it seems that I am getting improper indentation errors from python, even though the code LOOKS good.

I can solve this by running `set et|retab` every time before I save, but that seems wrong and cumbersome.

What might I be missing?  And if this should be somewhere else in StackExchange, let me know.

Thanks.

--edit--

`verbose setlocal et?`
gives this:

> expandtab
>           Last set from ~/.vimrc

which is what I expect

relevant portion of .vimrc:

set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab

---

No vim version changes in quite a few months.  I think windows may have had one of its update parties late last week or early this week.  Which may or may not be a coincidence.

Comment: have you changed version of vim? have you played with your configuration recently? You should perhaps look at expandtab. You're mixing tabs and spaces in the same python file, retab fixes that. The reason the problem started is, right now, a mystery.

Comment: What are your indent settings? `:verbose setlocal et?` When you `:set et`, does this really get reverted to `noet` after a save?

Comment: I understand that retab is fixing it, I am wondering why this is happening.  Fixing a broken file is no big deal, but I am trying to figure out why it keeps getting broken.

Comment: If `et` is kept set, then it must be something inserting literal `<Tab>` characters. Do you have any plugins / mappings (there were recently updated)?

Comment: No plugins or new mappings.  Only two things I can think of are Windows updates.  (I need to convince my corporate masters to let me use linux), or possibly the fact that I have another system that touched a few of these files and then checked them into bitbucket.  But I have not done a check from that machine in days, and I see the problem reoccur several times a day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, weirdness went away.  Maybe just over time, maybe it was more Windows updates.  Dunno, but all better now.  Sigh.  I hate problems that fix themselves.  They always worry me.

Answer (score 2):

I am having a similar problem funnily only with `*.slim` files. I solved it by forcing a retab for those files on every `:write` in my `.vimrc`:

```
fu! ResetSpaces()
    set tabstop=2
    set noexpandtab
    %retab!
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePre *.slim :call ResetSpaces()
```